# Blowing in Wool Insulation

Tags: insulation

We bought a house in Northern Arctic Minnesota last summer. After outrageous propane consumption this last winter I decided to check out the insulation in the attic. This summer a leak developed and drywall ended up in our bedroom. After realizing that there was no access to the attic, I made a hole in the gable and found extreme heat. We have since replaced the roofing and a ridge vent. I also have installed a thermostatically controlled fan in the gable. While up there I found that there was only one layer of fiberglass batting... It was white?? Never seen the white stuff before. It has R-30 marked on it and 10".. It has settled to around 7"...

Anyhow, the recommended R-value for our region is R-49 to R-60... The local lumber yard has a great sale on "Blowing Wool Insulation". Retail $35 down to $19 with rebate and sale. So, I picked up 30 bags.I am considering blowing in at an R-30 value over the R-30 batting that is already in there. Should give me the recommended R-60.

I am an amateur and am thinking about getting someone with experience to blow it in. However, if it is a no-brainer, I would like to do it myself.??

Also, I was wondering if I have to do anything special around the soffits/vents (perforated for venting) inside?

There is an older part of the house (early 1900s) with about 7 inches of blown-in cellulose. Can I just blow in some of the wool over it?

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Have you considered that the attic might not be the only place you need to insulate? I'd check for heat/air leaks with a thermal camera (or have someone do that for you) *well* before buying any insulation if I were in your shoes

Comment: It's easy, just don't block the soffit vents.   I made cardboard channels and just slid them down to the vents.

Answer (score -1):

My house had the white ( fiberglas ) blown in 20 years ago.  It was a nasty job with full coveralls ,mask, headcover and a trailer mounted blower unit. How would you do it ?  I had covered some soffits with pieces foam board an supposedly the operator tried not to cover the rest.

Comment: I'm not quite getting it. Do you mean you would be used like 1 inch foam board to create like a chimney up each of the channels so that the blown in insulation doesn't cover them up?

Comment: I wedged the foam vertically between rafters to stop the fiberglas from going onto the soffit to plug the vent screen.